# Testing on pre-IOS4

Tags: testing, ios, ios-simulator, ios3.0

I have a problem with an app that works perfect on my iPhone 4, and on my 3Gs but both are on iOS 4. BUT, when a colleague installed it on his 3G with 3.1.2 on it... it crashes on startup.

Is there someway I can test to install the app in a 3.1.2 simulator of some kind?

He didn't send me his crash logs yet.

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this for the simulator, but you can find links for the old SDKs here:

http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/

You should be able to install the old simulator SDKs and have them show up in the simulator menu.

Comment: I'll have a look at it... sounds good anyway. Too bad it takes another 20 - 30 min to download the files... they are about 3gb each. :(

Comment: The simulator seems to "hang" itself. Seems quite an hack.

Comment: Bummer. I'd only done it with an actual device. I assume you're trying it in the iphone 3 simulator?

Comment: Yes, thats what I did. What I did manage to do is to install the previouse xcode and test it using that xcode... and weak link the UIkit.framework. Which also solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with multiple SDKs has proved to be extremely painful in my experience. If you end up installing an old SDK, I'd recommend you install it in a separate "Developer" folder.

In my opinion, the best way to deal with 3.x debugging is to get your hand on an old iPod touch with 3.x installed. You can get one for pretty cheap from a local classified ads site and it really makes 3.x debugging a lot easier.